# Maven Hangs Downloading Inside a Docker Container

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, coreos

I have a gitlab with gitlab ci and a runner all running fine in a CoreOs Machine.

All 3 services are running using the following dockerfiles service files and  build script:

Build Script:

```
git submodule update --init

ls -la

mvn install
```

CI service:

```
    [Unit]
    Description=CI

    # Requirements
    Requires=docker.service
    Requires=db.service
    Requires=gitlab.service
    Requires=redis.service


    # Dependency ordering
    After=docker.service
    After=db.service
    After=gitlab.service
    After=redis.service

    [Service]
    User=core

    # Let the process take awhile to start up (for first run Docker containers)
    TimeoutStartSec=0

    # Get CoreOS environmental variables
    EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

    # Pre-start and Start
    ## Directives with "=-" are allowed to fail without consequence
    KillMode=none
    Restart=always
    RestartSec=2

    ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill ci
    ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm ci
    ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull sameersbn/gitlab-ci:5.2.0
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name ci \
     -e 'DB_TYPE=mysql' -e 'DB_HOST=${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}' -e 'DB_NAME=***' -e 'DB_USER=***' -e 'DB_PASS=********'\
     -e 'REDIS_HOST=${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}' -e 'REDIS_PORT=6379'\
     -e 'GITLAB_URL=http://${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:8081/'\
     -e 'GITLAB_CI_HOST=${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}'\
     -e 'GITLAB_CI_PORT=8080'\
     -e 'GITLAB_CI_HTTPS=true'\
     -e 'GITLAB_CI_EMAIL=*****************'\
     -e 'SMTP_USER=**********' -e 'SMTP_PASS=**********'\
     -p 8080:80 \
     sameersbn/gitlab-ci:5.2.0

    # Stop
    ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop ci
```

CI-runner service:

```
        [Unit]
        Description=CI Runner Maven & Dart

        # Requirements
        Requires=docker.service
        Requires=ci.service
        Requires=db.service
        Requires=gitlab.service
        Requires=redis.service

        # Dependency ordering
        After=docker.service
        After=ci.service
        After=db.service
        After=gitlab.service
        After=redis.service


        [Service]
        User=core

        # Let the process take awhile to start up (for first run Docker containers)
        TimeoutStartSec=0

        RemainAfterExit=yes

        # Get CoreOS environmental variables
        EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment

        #Pre-start and Start
        ## Directives with "=-" are allowed to fail without consequence

        ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill ci-runner-maven-dart
        ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm ci-runner-maven-dart
        ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker pull registry.globaleda.pt/globaleda/ci-runner-maven-dart:latest
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name ci-runner-maven-dart -d \
            -v /data/ci-runner-maven-dart:/home/gitlab_ci_runner/data \
            registry.globaleda.pt/globaleda/ci-runner-maven-dart:latest

        # Stop
        ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop ci-runner-maven-dart
```

Ci runner dockerfile:

```
FROM lemonbar/gitlab-runner-jdk-maven:1.0
MAINTAINER jrofurtado@gmail.com

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install curl -y

# Install dartIn the dockerfile i added ENV MAVEN_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

RUN apt-get install apt-transport-https -y
RUN sh -c 'curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
RUN sh -c 'curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install dart -y
ENV DART_HOME /usr/lib/dart

RUN apt-get -y install ca-certificates curl
ADD globaleda.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
RUN git config --global http.sslverify false 
RUN apt-get update
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ | sudo sh
ENV DOCKER_HOST tcp://*************
ADD .dockercfg /
RUN rm -f /app/init
ADD init /app/
RUN chmod 777 /app/init
```

Ci dockerfile is unmodified version of sameersbn/gitlab-ci:5.2.0.

when i compile a maven project (with mvn install) it starts to download the required artifacts and the download hangs, if i retry the download over and over again it manages to fully download problem is i need to download all at once without interruptions (it manages to continue cause im storing all the downloads on a mapped volume)

Observations:

-I deployed the Ci runner container on my local machine instead of the server and linked to the gitlab ci and the problem persists.

-If you go inside the container (with docker-enter script  or docker exec container bash) and run mvn install on a terminal it downloads everything as it should, although downloading it within the build it hangs.

-i tried using Setting MAVEN_OPTS to -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true on dockerfile of CI-Runner,i also tried to include it in the build script of CI-Runner to force this variable:

- In the dockerfile i added ENV MAVEN_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
- In the build script i added MAVEN_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

> -Running in debug mode (-e) or reading the logs the only information i have is :Download Timeout

Comment: It seems some network permission/firewall problem. Try to use the same user that your script is running and test the `mvn install` command again and see if it download what it is needed.

Comment: I just tested what you said and both users are root so thats not the problem =(

Comment: Was it the docker run command that was hanging? I had fun before but with docker exec. 1. fun with ttys 2. hang/freeze docker exec run under timeout. 1. jenkins job -> script ssh to test driver -> ssh to system-under-test -> bash script -> calls docker exec. Ssh tty flags had to be used in a particular way to get things working. 2. There seem to be various docker exec hanging issues e.g. this one particular to my experience: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/28207

Comment: I cant remenber to be honest its been almost 2 years but i think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Maven doesnt actually hangs, the build is completed successfully.But the runner doesnt communicate to the gitlab ci saying it made its work sucessfully due to a response error: 500.

```
>     2015-01-02 18:37:54 +0000 | Submitting build 439 to coordinator...response error: 500
>     2015-01-02 18:38:02 +0000 | Submitting build 439 to coordinator...response error: 500
>     2015-01-02 18:38:06 +0000 | Completed build 439, success.
>     2015-01-02 18:38:06 +0000 | Submitting build 439 to coordinator...response error: 500
>     2015-01-02 18:38:15 +0000 | Submitting build 439 to coordinator...response error: 500
>     2015-01-02 18:38:18 +0000 | Completed build 439, success.
>     2015-01-02 18:38:18 +0000 | Submitting build 439 to coordinator...response error: 500
>     2015-01-02 18:38:27 +0000 | Submitting build 439 to coordinator...response error: 500
>     2015-01-02 18:38:30 +0000 | Completed build 439, success.
>     2015-01-02 18:38:30 +0000 | Submitting build 439 to coordinator...response error: 500
>     2015-01-02 18:38:39 +0000 | Submitting build 439 to coordinator...response error: 500
```

Answer (score 1):

### Make sure your VPN is OFF ;-)

I came here googling the same issue. After reading the comments below OP

> It seems some network permission/firewall problem.

I remembered that I was using a VPN connection. Turning off VPN solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

encountered the case with Docker-in-docker running container builds in gitlab runners (that in addition ran in an OpenShift cluster!).

The simple `docker build -t $REPO_IMAGE_TAG .` hangs indefinitely on the very first maven download, although working like a breeze in my IDE.

If I connect as a terminal to the hanging gitlab runner instance, I can execute for instance a `wget <url-from-logs-over-which-maven-hangs>` fine. Henceforth, there's no core networking or DNS issue. (tip: check this by running 'wget' in the gitlab-ci script if you can't connect as a terminal).

Upon such condition, try in your gitlab-ci scripts:

`docker build --network host -t $REPO_IMAGE_TAG .`

The extra option tells docker to use the built-in 'host' network driver (i.e. access the gitlab-runner networking stack directly) in place of the default 'bridge' mode.